# timestamp difference of two files in unix shell

Tags: unix, timestamp, solaris

I have two files. I need to calculate the timestamp difference between the two files.

I need the timestamp difference between test1 and test2:
    -rw-r--r--   1 root     root           1 Aug 16 16:26 test1
    -rw-r--r--   1 root     root           2 Dec 13  2010 test2

I need the timestamp difference between test3 and test4.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root           3 Aug 16 16:26 test3
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root           4 Aug 16 17:34 test4
```

Please let me know how we can achieve it in Solaris .
I am using Solaris and my machine info is :

```
- Sol 5.10 Generic_127128-11 i86pc i386 i86pc.
```

If you need to know anything else please let me know.

I have got the below answer date conversion to seconds in Solaris.

```
truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 | grep ^time | awk -F"= " '{print $2}'
```

but this is for the current date .. how we can do it for file (for example test3, as above)?

Comment: At what precision level do you want time stamp difference i.e in days,hours or minutes?

Answer (score 4):

The stat(1) command can show the time stamp in seconds-since-epoch:

```
stat --printf '%Y\n' foo
```

Thus something like the following might work:

```
(stat --printf '%Y' test2; printf ' - '; stat --printf '%Y\n' test4) | bc -lq
```

Tweak as required.

Comment: stat is part of coreutils, which is usually installed on every Linux system, except embedded ones, so I'm surprised if you don't have it. Or perhaps you're using another Unix system? You'll need to provide provide more context and information for more help, I guess. (Like: what system you're using, and what the exact errors are. Edit your question to do that, please.)

Comment: hey first of all thx.... I am using solaris and my machine info is :-  Sol 5.10 Generic_127128-11 i86pc i386 i86pc. if u need anything else pls let me now

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to get the date in seconds

```
date +%s -d "`ls -l test1 | awk -F " " '{ print $6,$7 }'`"
```

Comment: its not working :( . throwing below error:-                                        bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
awk: can't open { print $6,$7 }

Comment: this command is not working on solaris ..... do u have any other command which can work on solaris

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls -l .bashrc*
-rw-r--r-- 1 max max 360 Dec 14  2010 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 max max 359 Dec  2  2010 .bashrc~

$ echo $((`stat --format=%Y .bashrc` - `stat --format=%Y .bashrc~`))
1018884
```

The `$(())` syntax is bash arithmetic expression expansion. What happens above is that file timestamps in seconds since Unix epoch get subtracted and the difference is printed.

Comment: On linux ur command is working..... but on solaris it says stat command not found. could you plese tell me stat is a solaris command or not?

Comment: The first thing you want to do on Solaris is install GNU tools. http://sunfreeware.com/indexintel10.html